# Call a function within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use `ng-repeat` to load an image, move it to a the appropriate position while playing it's associated tone. Then proceed with doing the same with the next image (one at a time). The issue I am having is that when I try to call my play function, it is calling them all at the same time. Therefore  I am getting the error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
>   by a new load request.

The reason I am using `getAudioSrc()` for my `ng-src` is because if I don't I get the error

> Error while interpolating:
>   ../Content/Game/Audio/{{it.Tone.ToneFileName}}

Most of the things I could find was in regards to calling a function on the `ng-click` event. Since there is no click event I used `ng-init`

```
<div class="circle-container">
    <div ng-repeat="it in model.imageTones | orderBy:Position">
        <img ng-src="../Content/Game/Animals/{{it.Image.ImageFileName}}" ng-style="{'transform': 'rotate(' + (it.Position*30) + 'deg) translate(19em) rotate(-' + (it.Position*30) + 'deg)'}" />
        <audio id="audioPlayed" ng-src="{{model.getAudioSrc(it.Tone.ToneFileName)}}" ng-init="model.play()"></audio>
    </div>
</div>




module.component("gameLts",
{
    templateUrl: "../GameAngular/game-lts.html",
    bindings: {
        imageTones: "<"
    },
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: function() {
        var model = this;

        model.getAudioSrc = function(toneFileName) {
            return '../Content/Game/Audio/' + toneFileName;
        };

        model.play = function () {
            $("#audioPlayed")[0].play();
        };
}
```

Comment: can u try calling 'play' function outside ng-repeat and once component is loaded, call the function with first index manually

Comment: If i call it inside the component I get `Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`

Comment: You need to wait for the [HTML Audio/Video DOM ended Event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp).